# replace column values with values from other colum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "companies" which contains companies which are in a relationship to each other. I want to replace the company name in the "Partner" column with the corresponding ID.

```
ID  Company     Partner

1   Company A   Company B
2   Company B   Company C
3   Company C   Company B
```

should become:

```
ID  Company     Partner

1   Company A   2
2   Company B   3
3   Company C   2
```

I have tried this, but getting an error that the Subquery returns more than one result:

```
UPDATE Companies c1
SET Partner =
(SELECT DISTINCT c2.ID FROM Companies c3 JOIN Companies c2 ON c3.Partner = c2.Company
    WHERE c1.Partner = c3.Partner
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Companies c JOIN
       Companies cp
       ON c.Partner = cp.Company
    SET c.Partner = cp.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this 'INNER JOIN` on partner name and company name.

```
 Update p set p.partner = pt.id from partner as p inner join (
 select id, company from partner ) AS PT on p.partner=pt.company
```